# Spring cloud gateway MVC issues with modifyRequestBody

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-cloud-gateway

Im trying to use the new spring-cloud-gateway-mvc to modify the request body.

I'm using Spring Boot 3.2.2 and Spring Cloud 2023.0.0

I have tried doing a simple proxy forward, and that works just fine like this:

```
@Bean
RouterFunction<ServerResponse> testRoute(){
    return route()
            .route(path("/test").and(method(HttpMethod.POST)), http("http://httpbin.org"))
            .before(setPath("/post"))
            .build();
}
```

.. but as soon as i try to read or modify the request body, I get an exception:

```
@Bean
RouterFunction<ServerResponse> testRoute(){
    return route()
            .route(path("/test").and(method(HttpMethod.POST)), http("http://httpbin.org"))
            .before(setPath("/post"))
            .before(modifyRequestBody(String.class, String.class, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, (serverRequest, s) -> {
                LOGGER.info(s);
                return s;
            })).build();
}
```

Exception:
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.util.Map.put(Object, Object)" because the return value of "org.springframework.cloud.gateway.server.mvc.common.MvcUtils.getGatewayAttributes(org.springframework.web.servlet.function.ServerRequest)" is null] with root cause

I'm sure that i'm doing something wrong with this simple exception, but I can't figure out what as i'm pretty much doing the same thing that's mentioned in the documentation:
[Spring-Cloud-Gateway-MVC ModifyRequestBody Filter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/reference/spring-cloud-gateway-server-mvc/filters/modifyrequestbody.html)

Does anyone have an idea of what i'm doing wrong?